# Azure difference between General-purpose v2 storage accounts and BlockBlobStorage accounts explained?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to create some new storage accounts in Azure. Naturally, I want to know which are best suited and cheapest for different cases. As far as I can tell the only relevant accounts for me are "[General-purpose v2 accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#general-purpose-v2-accounts)" and "[BlockBlobStorage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#blockblobstorage-accounts)", but I have a bit of a problem understanding the exact difference in performance and costs.
Could anyone elaborate?

Regarding costs of the accounts, I found some information here for [V2](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/storage/data-lake/) and [BlockBlobs pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/storage/blobs/), but I am not really sure if they really represent the storage classes from Azure (as the naming is a bit of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance, [BlockBlobStorage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#blockblobstorage-accounts) provide low, consistent latency and higher transaction rates. So it has good performance.

For cost(here is [the link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/) to pricing page), since `BlockBlobStorage accounts` does not support [tiering to hot, cool, or archive access tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#access-tiers-for-block-blob-data), it will cost more than [General-purpose v2 accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#general-purpose-v2-accounts). General-purpose v2 accounts support tiering like `hot / cool / archive`, which costs little, please refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

And [the link for V2 pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/pricing/details/storage/data-lake/) in your question is incorrect, it's for [azure data lake storage v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction) which is different than `General-purpose v2 accounts`.