# Is Azure BlockBlobStorage or General-Purpose v2 better for premium, low-latency, lots of small json files with search?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cognitive-search, azure-data-lake-gen2

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview) suggests that BlockBlobStorage is ideal for my scenario, where I have lots of small JSON files and want low-latency and expect a lot of upsert activity plus use of Azure Cognitive Search. I will be arranging my files in folders (one entity type and therefore indexing strategy per sub-folder), and it looks like General-Purpose v2 potentially has some benefits here by turning on hierarchical namespaces to then become Azure Data Lake Storage v2. That said, it looks like search by subfolder is possible even without ADLS v2 via the SearchIndexerDataContainer.Query parameter. So I'm left wondering whether BlockBlobStorage has a significant enough advantage in terms of low-latency and high transaction rates as that link implies.
(Note: I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952299/azure-difference-between-general-purpose-v2-storage-accounts-and-blockblobstorag) but it didn't really answer my question.)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I learned this from Microsoft just now:

"Premium is based on SSD’s and therefore is ideal for small objects and, low and consistent latency.  GPv2 is HDD based."